# Normal map baking gradients instead of "flatness"

Tags: normals, baking

The normal map I'm baking shows gradients for "flat" edges, which seems wrong, and when I import to Substance Painter, it confirms they're wrong (3rd screenshot).

- I have low and high poly models.
- I have smooth shading on both models.
- I have a cage model that is slightly larger than the low poly model.

The really weird part is, the render looks right in the viewport for some strange reason (the low poly model looks like the high poly model, as if the normal map is working, even though that seems impossible looking at the baked map).  When I export the .fbx and normal map and import to Substance Painter, the normals look really wrong.

[image: screencapture]

EDIT: Baking parameters
[image]

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1404/

Comment: Your screenshot does not show us the baking parameters.  Is it for object or tangent space?  Does the target texture use the same Image Sampling?

Comment: Oh man I forgot to add that, sorry.  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1369
Tangent. Margin 3px. Selected to Active. Cage. Extrusion 0.00. Bake Type: Normal.

Comment: You might have to create a small .blend file that illustrates the problem and upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ .  The problem is not apparent just from the screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted the .blend file from the original post.  [Here's the .blend file.](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1404/)

Comment: After experimenting with this scene for a while, I am also severely confused by what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use edge splits on sharp corners.

Set the whole object to smooth shading, select the edges to be sharp, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and select Mark Sharp. Then add the Edge Split modifier. You might skip marking edges sharp manually and rely on the angle based edge splitting.